# Webservice with security headers

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I'm trying to consume a third party webservice (from the Component Interface in Peoplesoft), but in order to authenticate I have to have a header that looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">

    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">    
      <wsse:UsernameToken>    
        <wsse:Username>X</wsse:Username>    
        <wsse:Password>X</wsse:Password>    
      </wsse:UsernameToken>    
    </wsse:Security>    
  </soapenv:Header>
```

I added a block to the web.config file in my app that's trying to use the webservice as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <header>
                <endpoint>
                    <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                        <wsse:UsernameToken>
                            <wsse:Username>X</wsse:Username>
                            <wsse:Password>X</wsse:Password>
                        </wsse:UsernameToken>
                    </wsse:Security>
                </endpoint>
            </header>
        </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But the header still doesn't appear in the XML request to the webservice.

Am I even on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 2.0 to connect to the service, your best bet is to download [WSE 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=018a09fd-3a74-43c5-8ec1-8d789091255d&displaylang=en) ([WSE 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fc5f06c5-821f-41d3-a4fe-6c7b56423841&displaylang=en) if you're using .NET 1.1).

If you're using WCF to connect to the service, here's a link that should help you along your way. It's about the proper way to implement the WS-Security standard in WCF:

[Enterprise .NET Community: Security your WCF Services](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=SecuringWCFService)

Comment: None of the above as far as I know. I added a web reference in Visual Studio 2008 (.NET 3.5).

Comment: Then, if I remember correctly, the default behavior should be to create WCF bindings to the Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/03db0772-b319-468c-9298-0ec301dacf34

I never though WCF will not allow a simple username token on http